# Wordpress: code in the head and in the body not displayed

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress and I have problems with inserting code in the head and body (Google Tag Manager, Analytics and others). I have always inserted everything with special plugins or by handing the header.php file or through the functions.php (by inserting the correct snippet of code necessary to inject everything). Also I was advised to disable plugins that might block the use of cookies (which is why I might not see the injected code). Unfortunately, however, after numerous attempts I continue to not display anything, even if I brutally insert the code in the head of the header.php file,(which has always worked) do you have any advice? I don't know what to do .. thanks!

Comment: Maybe your theme lacks the `wp_body_open()` call right after the `<body>` so plugins can't inject properly. This doesn't explain though why directly editing `header.php` didn't work.

Comment: wp_body_open() it is present correctly at the opening of the <body>..

Comment: So it's probably not the correct `header.php`. Or it is a page which has a different template than the one that includes `header.php`. Try eliminating files until you find the correct one. Oh... and maybe there is some caching plugin involved?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't want to use a plugin, however, if using the Site Kit plugin it ads only the Tag Manager snippet as recommended by the Tag Manager service. It also doesn't add anything other than the Tag Manager code, as evident from checking your sites source code after choosing to allow Site Kit to insert the snippet for you.

The above also ensures that any theme change or update doesn't result in you having to once again insert your snippet manually.